# Sort the tweets by date using Twitter Search API

Tags: php, twitter

I have written an application that searches tweets for a specific keyword using the twitter API, but i am trying to find a way to display the latest tweets first, i am unable to find a way to sort the tweets received as a response.

I am referring to link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets and below is my code

I have included all necessary files and set all required parameters

```
    function search(array $query)
{
  $toa = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  return $toa->get('search/tweets', $query);
}

$query = array(
  "q" => "Sachin Tendulkar",
  "count" => 10,
  "result_type" => "popular"
 );

$results = search($query);
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don’t see any possibility to ask for the results to be ordered in the docs … but for just 10 results, ordering them afterwards in your script should be no problem either.

Comment: Hello Cbore, Thanks for your reply, actually 10 is just a place holder, it could be more

Comment: Still doesn’t matter that much, sorting arrays is quite quick in PHP.

Comment: OK, Yes thats true, but is there possibility that i might miss some data, i.e. say if i load 100 tweets, will there be a possibility that i might miss on some latest stuff?

Comment: OK, so this is more about the _selection_ of results in the first place, and less about ordering of the results already selected. For that they seem to offer only the `result_type` parameter. And if you are worried about “missing some data”, you should maybe read the comment regarding that on top of the page first …

Comment: Thanks CBore For your help

Answer (score 1):

To display the latest tweet, you should use `result_type` as `recent`.

```
$query = array(
  "q" => "Sachin Tendulkar",
  "count" => 10,
  "result_type" => "recent"
 );
```

More about `result_type` paramater :

- mixed: Include both popular and real time results in the response.
- recent: return only the most recent results in the response.
- popular: return only the most popular results in the response.

Comment: Hi Yuva Raj Thanks for your comment but i want the result to be sorted, how can i do that

Comment: Sort, on what basis do you want to sort?

Comment: I want to sort on Created Date

Comment: If you run the above code, you will get tweets like 10.30,10.29,10.28,10.27 (for ex). You can try by accessing `created_at`.

Comment: I get unsorted list, i.e i get a tweet of nov 2012 followed by  nov 2013, i want the latest always to be on top